# How to add a spaces in front of text in a single cell in latex document using Kable in R?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I am trying to add 2-4 spaces in front of the text in a single cell in kable. I want to do this for multiple rows. I was unable to make this work using the "align" option because it is too extreme for my purposes.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It will be easier for us to help if you provide a reproducible example. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If it's always the same, then `paste0("  ", df$column)` will do that. If you want to pad them based on current length, then perhaps something like `paste0(strrep(" ", max(nchar(df$column)) - nchar(df$column)), df$column)` or similar.

Comment: But `align=` is completely different. Since the font is likely not fixed-width, adding spaces will be imperfect at best, alignment is likely the better option. I suggest you [edit] your question and add more context, such as a starting point (some `data.frame`, please just a few relevant rows), the code you've attempted, and some method of communicating your expected output. Thanks!

Comment: You could use `str_pad()` from the `stringr` package, as another option.